# Come si spiega a uno straniero la differenza tra verbi transitivi e intransitivi?

Tags: verbs, difference

Sto facendo un tandem con una ragazza austriaca e vorrei riuscire a spiegarle la differenza tra verbi intransitivi e transitivi. 
Per me, in quanto madrelingua, basta domandarmi se il verbo risponde alla domanda "chi, che cosa" senza bisogno di una preposizione (insomma se il verbo regge un oggetto direttamente o no), in quel caso si tratta di transitivi. Altrimenti intransitivi. 
Purtroppo però questa consapevolezza manca a chi non è madrelingua italiano. 
Come potrei spiegare quindi come funzionano questi verbi? 
C'è una lista o qualcosa di simile che si possa seguire o imparare a memoria? Esiste qualche regola?

**Specifico meglio**: qualcuno tra di voi ha una lista di verbi transitivi e intransitivi in italiano? Il concetto in sè è chiaro, però a me interesserebbe proprio una lista con i verbi transitivi e quelli intransitivi.

Comment: In tedesco non esistono verbi transitivi e intransitivi? Quanto meno, i primi corrispondono a quelli che reggono l'accusativo. Il tuo problema è spiegarlo in italiano senza ricorrere ad analogie con la sua lingua di partenza? Più che una lista, semmai farei vari esempi (mangiare, guardare, prendere...) e controesempi (andare, volare...).

Comment: Concordo con @DaG. Ci sono verbi che, credo, sono intrinsecamente transitivi o intransitivi in tutte le lingue. Piú che un problema specifico della lingua italiana, è un problema di nozioni individuali di grammatica, in generale.

Comment: Uhm non sono molto d´accordo. Ogni lingua regge i suoi complementi un pò come vuole e per me è quasi ovvio dovermi studiare a memoria come un verbo in una specifica lingua funzioni. Non credo sia buono pensarlo all'italiana e credere che il verbo funzioni allo stesso modo, perchè troppo spesso putroppo non è così. 
Esempio: 

io ti telefono (io telefono a te) (telefonare regge il compl. di termine : a chi?= intransitivo) 

in tedesco invece 
ich rufe dich an (è transitivo!) 
ich frage dich

Comment: E.V., il mio suggerimento era solo di procedere per analogia per spiegare il concetto generale di transitività, se la tua collega ne ha bisogno, non di dare per scontato che singoli verbi con lo stesso significato si costruiscano nello stesso modo (ammesso pure che tra due lingue si possa mai parlare di “stesso significato”).

Comment: @E.V. La mia è un’estensione indebita, d’accordo, ma partendo dalla definizione generale, classica di transitività, credo che un verbo come _mangiare_ sia transitivo un po’ in tutte le lingue. (È una mia supposizione, naturalmente.) Insomma, mi pare di poter dire che ci sono verbi _fondamentali_ (_mangiare_, _vedere_, _andare_, ecc.), che denotano azioni comuni a tutti gli esseri umani, che _possono_ fungere da base per un confronto interlinguistico, in specie per lingue in un modo o nell’altro affini e imparentate (alla lontanissima, in questo caso).

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Anche nelle lingue ergative? ;-)

Comment: La definizione di transitivo e intransitivo è la stessa tra italiano e francese, ma in francese "scendere il bambino" è assolutamente corretto mentre in italiano no... :D

Comment: @DaG Non saprei, non sono molto ferrato al riguardo. Nel basco _vedere_, tanto per fare un esempio, è intransitivo? Boh. Diciamo che volevo fornire a E.V. un espediente pratico per venirne fuori facilmente. Dopotutto italiano e tedesco sono, per cosí dire, cugini di secondo grado.

Comment: Transitivi: mangiare, vedere, toccare, sentire. Intransitivi: camminare, dormire, ridere, nuotare. Tra gl’intransitivi ho messo solo verbi inergativi: a un primissimo livello di conoscenza di questi concetti fondamentali è opportuno non insinuare dubbi, nemmeno sottili. I verbi inaccusativi in italiano hanno caratteristiche particolari, come la possibilità di posposizione del soggetto in costrutti non marcati (es. «è arrivato il treno»). Cosí, puoi confrontare meglio due frasi con due verbi distinti: es. «Mario tocca [la statua]» ~ «Mario dorme [/]».

Comment: Aggiungo un link alla mia risposta.

Answer (score 5):

La distinzione tra verbi transitivi e intransitivi non è propria della lingua italiana, essa esiste in francese, spagnolo e anche tedesco.

E come in italiano, anche in tedesco i verbi transitivi sono verbi seguiti dall'accusativo che rispondono alla domanda “Wen/Was?”/ “Chi/Che cosa?”. Sono inoltre verbi che possono formare il passivo e in tal caso il complemento oggetto diventa soggetto.

I verbi intransitivi, al contrario, sono quei verbi che NON sono seguiti dal complemento oggetto e che normalmente non formano il passivo poichè manca il complemento oggetto da poter trasformare in soggetto nella frase passiva.

Esistono verbi transitivi in una lingua che sono intransitivi in un'altra, ma la regola grammaticale non cambia da una lingua all'altra.

Comment: Non dovrebbe essere “Wer”?

Comment: Nella risposta dovrebbe essere "wer" (compl. oggetto) ma nella domanda "wen" (soggetto). O no? :D

Answer (score 1):

Queste spiegazioni sono tratte dai libri *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo (edizioni ELI) e *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* di Maria Cristina Peccianti (Giunti Editori). Penso che si tratti proprio di spiegazioni facili da capire dagli studenti stranieri.

> Si chiamano **transitivi** i verbi che possono avere un **complemento oggetto** (o **complemento diretto**).
>
> Si chiamano **intransitivi** i verbi che non possono avere un **complemento oggetto** (o **complemento diretto**).
>
> Il **complemento oggetto** (o **complemento diretto**) è il tipo di complemento che serve a determinare la persona o la cosa che subisce l'azione da parte del soggetto. Per esempio: Mangio ***la mela*** --> "la mela" è il complemento oggetto di questa frase. Dunque, "mangiare" è un verbo transitivo.
>
> Sono generalmente intransitivi i verbi che indicano movimento (*andare, venire, partire, ecc.*), i verbi che indicano uno stato o un cambiamento della persona (*guarire, arrossire, invecchiare, morire, ecc.*), i verbi pronominali (*vergognarsi, pentirsi, annoiarsi, ecc.*) e altri.

In [questo link](http://www.saenaiulia.com/_01/verbi-italiani/lista-verbi.php?chr=A) si trova una lista di verbi transitivi e intransitivi.

Comment: Aggiungerei anche i verbi riflessivi tra quelli generalmente intransitivi.

PS: non riesco a correggere un errore nel tuo post: `facili DA capire` e non `DI capire`

Comment: @RiccardoI.: L'ho corretto. Grazie mille!