# Cosa significa “Sto facendo un tandem con una ragazza austriaca”?

Tags: word-meaning

In questo post “[Come si spiega a uno straniero la differenza tra verbi transitivi e intransitivi?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/come-si-spiega-a-uno-straniero-la-differenza-tra-verbi-transitivi-e-intransitivi)” è scritto:

> Sto facendo un *tandem con una ragazza austriaca* e vorrei riuscire a spiegarle la differenza tra verbi intransitivi e transitivi.

Cosa significhi lì *tandem con una ragazza austriaca* è, per me, incomprensibile.

C'è qualcuno che saprebbe spiegarlo?

Comment: Elberich, hai davvero provato a cercarlo su Google? [Questa domanda è off-topic per Italian SE](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-we-admit-easily-answerable-questions?lq=1), dato che non è cosi difficile a trovare una risposta su Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

Ahahh quel post è mio! 
Ti spiego subito. 
Per tandem lì intendo il "tandem linguistico", non andare in bicicletta in due (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_linguistico).

Si tratta di un metodo geniale di praticare e migliorare nella conoscenza della lingua parlata. Due madrelingua che vogliono imparare la lingua dell'altro si incontrano e parlano e si correggono! 
Di base può essere organizzato come si vuole, noi di solito ci incontriamo in un bar e parliamo un'ora italiano e un'ora tedesco.

Comment: Come mai questa risposta ha ricevuto un voto negativo?

Comment: Neanch'io capisco la ragione del voto negativo.

Comment: +1 per simpatia e perché è un metodo molto efficace.

Comment: @dag Io votai +1, ma forse il downvote è dovuto al fatto che la risposta inizia con 'Ahahh'.

Comment: @charo, facciamo un tandem? Io ti insegno l'italiano, tu mi insegni lo spagnolo.

Answer (score 4):

Si tratta di un uso figurato del termine ***tandem***:

> - Bicicletta a due posti, uno dietro l'altro

[image]

***Il tandem linguistico***:

> - è un metodo di apprendimento delle lingue. Si può imparare una lingua straniera trovando un partner madrelingua e attivando una conversazione. Ciascuno dei due partecipanti è madrelingua della lingua che l'altro vuole apprendere.
> - Molte scuole e università in tutto il mondo organizzano corsi di lingue anche attraverso questo metodo. Alcuni esempi di questo metodo si possono anche trovare in siti web, come per esempio [Lang-8](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang-8).

[Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_linguistico)